# input multiple always sending size of 5

Tags: php, html, forms, input

```
<form action="entergallery.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<select id="photolib" name="photolib">
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `galleries`";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_row($res)){
    echo '<option value="'.$rows[3].'">'.$rows[1].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple/>
<input type="submit" id="upload" name="upload" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

For some reason this form always passing a length of 5. The enter gallery.php is just count{$_FILES['uploads']); and it always outputs 5 even if you don't enter any files. i have no clue how to solve this. I've tested this in multiple browsers and have the same problem in all
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

`count{$_FILES['uploads'])`

use

`count($_FILES['uploads']['name'])`

you will get the actual count.

Answer (score 1):

see $_FILES array structure

There is 5 elements always.

```
$_FILES["file"]["name"] - the name of the uploaded file
$_FILES["file"]["type"] - the type of the uploaded file
$_FILES["file"]["size"] - the size in bytes of the uploaded file
$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] - the name of the temporary copy of the file stored on the server
$_FILES["file"]["error"] - the error code resulting from the file upload
```

If you want check $_FILES for empty, you need check for upload error, like this

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
?>
```

In your case, with multiple files upload you has structure:

```
array
  'filesToUpload' => 
    array
      'name' => 
        array
          0 => string '2012-07-19_192449.jpg' (length=21)
          1 => string '2012-07-19_192449.png' (length=21)
      'type' => 
        array
          0 => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
          1 => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array
          0 => string '/tmp/phpBp3Pf7' (length=14)
          1 => string '/tmp/php4A25Ly' (length=14)
      'error' => 
        array
          0 => int 0
          1 => int 0
      'size' => 
        array
          0 => int 5263
          1 => int 8681
```

so, files count you can calculate in tmp_name array of filesUpload array, for example